# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.observe on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am getting the following error

I am using Android architecture components and tried to instantiate viewmodel and Observe data from LiveData. But im stuck here please help me solve this issue :

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, android.arch.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference
```

My Fragment is this :
While calling getCompany() method im getting and NullPoint Exception Error

```
    public class CompanyFragment extends LifecycleFragment {
    private CompanyViewModel companyViewModel;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        companyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CompanyViewModel.class);
        companyViewModel.initData();
        companyViewModel.getCompany().observe(this, new Observer<CompanyEntity>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable CompanyEntity companyEntity) {

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_company, container, false);
    }
}
```

My ViewModel class is this :

```
public class CompanyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LiveData<CompanyEntity> companyEntityLiveData;
    private CompanyRepository companyRepo;

    public CompanyViewModel() {}

    public CompanyViewModel(CompanyRepository companyRepo){
        this.companyRepo = companyRepo;
    }

    public void initData(){
        companyEntityLiveData = companyRepo.getCompany();
    }

    public LiveData<CompanyEntity> getCompany() {
        return companyEntityLiveData;
    }

}
```

Error is at this line :

```
   companyViewModel.getCompany().observe(this, new Observer<CompanyEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable CompanyEntity companyEntity) {

        }
    });
```

This is my CompanyRepository class:

```
public class CompanyRepository {
private WebService webService;

    public CompanyRepository(){

    }

    public LiveData<CompanyEntity> getCompany() {
        final MutableLiveData<CompanyEntity> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

        webService.getCompany().enqueue(new Callback<CompanyEntity>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CompanyEntity> call, Response<CompanyEntity> response) {
                data.setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CompanyEntity> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: `companyRepo.getCompany()` returns `null`, apparently.

Comment: This is my CompanyRepository class which makes REST call using Retrofit and returns liost of company data.

Comment: How ca fix it!! Can you please help me?

Comment: "Can you please help me?" -- we do not have the code to `companyRepo.getCompany()` and therefore have no idea why it might be returning `null`. You may wish to edit your question and post the code to `CompanyRepository`.

Comment: Edited question please check now.

Comment: I cannot explain how you are getting this crash. The best that I can recommend is to step through the `initData()` and `getCompany()` calls on your view model and see what's going on.

Comment: Check that inside initData() the companyRepo.getCompany() return not null

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must observe the same instance of your LiveData. In your `CompanyRepository` class you create a new LiveData instance every time you access the company, which means your activity is then observing an old instance.

The getCompany method should be changed to always return the same instance of the LiveData. Also, you should change setValue() to postValue() because you are trying to update the value on a background thread.

```
final MutableLiveData<CompanyEntity> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
public LiveData<CompanyEntity> getCompany() {

    webService.getCompany().enqueue(new Callback<CompanyEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CompanyEntity> call, Response<CompanyEntity> response) {
            data.postValue(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CompanyEntity> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe You can have declared a LiveData object after the method.

That's what happened to me in my case.

```
fun aMethod() {
    _aLiveData.value = Unit
}

private val _aLiveData = MutableLiveData<Unit>()
val aLiveData: LiveData<Unit> = _aLiveData
```

In fact, it should have been as follows.

```
private val _aLiveData = MutableLiveData<Unit>()
val aLiveData: LiveData<Unit> = _aLiveData

fun aMethod() {
    _aLiveData.value = Unit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public CompanyViewModel(){
    companyRepo= new companyRepo();
}

public LiveData<CompanyEntity> getCompany() {
    if(companyEntityLiveData==null)
        companyEntityLiveData= companyRepo.getSection();
    return companyEntityLiveData;
}
```

And in your Fragment:

```
    CompanyViewModel companyViewModel= 
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CompanyViewModel .class);
    LiveData<CompanyEntity> s = companyViewModel.getCompany();

    s.observe(this, new Observer<CompanyEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable CompanyEntity companyEntity) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Go go go", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer, to better help future visitors to this question where their problem might be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

In getCompany method you need to check whether companyEntityLiveData object is null, if so call service in it.

```
public LiveData<CompanyEntity> getCompany() {
    if(companyEntityLiveData == null){
       companyEntityLiveData = companyRepo.getCompany();
    }
    return companyEntityLiveData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use something that has not been initialized. **So in order not to depend on the order of execution, we must establish a safe nulability in the variable that stores what the repository returns**  `private val nullableObj: LiveData<T2>?`

With this we could use the property even before the repository has loaded it. Check the order of execution in the following example:

```
val aUse: LiveData<T> = MediatorLiveData<T>().apply {
    nullableObj?.let {
    }
}
private val nullableObj: LiveData<T2>? = repository::getNullableObj
```

---

Answering your question before using Repository #getCompany() check the nullability. In Kotlin:

```
companyVM.company?.observe(...) { ... }
```

GL

Answer (score 0):

companyRepo.getCompany() returns null, apparently.

This works for me.

Comment: Answer is unclear
As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).